# Change default direction for transitions

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery, css-transitions

Is there a way to change the direction for transitions globally?

I know we can change the type of transition like that:

```
$.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'slide';
```

But I would like to always have `reverse = true`.

By the way I know I can pass the direction when I change pages, but I want to default it for the whole app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the best way to do:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
    $.mobile.changePage.defaults.reverse = true;
});
```

I didn't see that in the doc though: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/globalconfig.html

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to the `pageinit` event for the pseudo-pages of your site and change the links in the current page:

```
$(document).delegate('.ui-page', 'pageinit', function () {
    $(this).find('[data-role="button"]').attr('data-direction', 'reverse');
});
```

All of your `data-role="button"` links will now use a reverse transition.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qJNDv/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's a good trick. I answered to my question with another way to do that I think is "better" in the way that it updates the global config.